# jQuery Change img src and do not display old

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm using jQuery to replace part of the image src path. It works perfectly but it still renders the old image before displaying the new image source. I was wondering if it's possible to use .hide() and .show() to prevent the old image from rendering.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", function(a, b) {
            return b.replace("s72-c", "s190-c")
        })
    })
});
```

Image url structure:

Old image url: http://www.example.com/s72-c/sample.jpg

New image url: http://www.example.com/s190-c/sample.jpg

Comment: if none of the answers are working or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` before iterating and `show()` within the iteration

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery img").hide().each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", function(a, b) {
            return b.replace("s72-c", "s190-c")
        });
        $(this).show();
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I didn't have the chance to test the code til today. I tried using your code and it only works if I set the original image to display:none using CSS. Looks like .hide() doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng, do you have a site I can look at or can you reproduce the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w9wq4rnd/ - If you try to 'Run' the code several times you will notice that it renders the old image first.

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng, did the fiddle solve the problem or is there other issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src",'');
        $(this).attr("src", function(a, b) {
            return b.replace("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Apple_seeds_-_variety_Gala_%28aka%29.jpg")
        })
    })
});
```

check this code

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAttr()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery img").each(function() {
        var src = this.src;
        $(this).removeAttr('src').attr("src", src.replace("s72-c", "s190-c"));
    })
});
```